# Trek Emonda 700OCLV - what does the RSL Race shop limited Stamp mean?

Tags: trek

I am looking for second hand bike and have my eye on a Trek Emonda, but I cannot seem to find much correct info on the internet.

It has Project one colours so it's hard to compare with other bikes.

But there is a RSL stamp on the frame on the top tube near the seat post. what does this mean? Most bikes I see have here Emonda written.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a sort of brand name to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Race Shop Limited" is what Trek uses to denote their more performance oriented framesets. It generally means that the frame will be the lightest of that particular model range and have a more aggressive geometry (their H1 fit, versus their normal H1.5 or H2 fits).

For the Emonda RSL: https://www.trekbikes.com/international/en_IN_TL/bikes/road-bikes/performance-road-bikes/%C3%A9monda/%C3%A9monda-slr/%C3%A9monda-slr-rsl-frame-set/p/29864/